# Follow up on increasing the possible migration routes for Writing SE

Tags: feature-request, migration, close-reasons

Follow up on [this question](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2369/community-specific-reasons-for-closing-only-shows-elu-and-writing-meta-se-optio).

After seeing [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359737/could-we-make-the-migration-search-function-for-moderators-be-made-available-to?noredirect=1#comment1200614_359737), [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359737/could-we-make-the-migration-search-function-for-moderators-be-made-available-to?noredirect=1#comment1200614_359737), and [this question](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2369/community-specific-reasons-for-closing-only-shows-elu-and-writing-meta-se-optio), I realize we can't add a search bar like the moderator tool on migration sites for regular users, but could we include several other sites **for Writing SE** as possible migration routes for regular users? I was thinking of adding Literature SE (for questions about already published books) and Law SE (for questions about copyright that are more law-focused) as possible migration routes. Would that be possible?